# Angular js bootstrap overlapping modals

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, overlapping

I just stumped upon this on my application, I'm using $modal service from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and since Bootstrap needs custom code for overlapping modals, I guess it needs custom code on angular-ui's $modal as well.

I don't even know where to start from, has anyone any hints on how to do this?

Here is a plunk to show the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/D8MNjG. Nothing happens when the another modal button is clicked within the 1st modal

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Solved please hava a look here [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KSsewObNMCc5MlE1Uz77?p=preview)

You missed ref to 'anotherModalController.js' in index file

Comment: BTW: no need to include jQuery nor bootstrap's JS: http://plnkr.co/edit/wVKLRxZaMx6iWJu7jOsM?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several things:
- your `index.html` does not load `anotherModalController.js`
- `ModalCtrl` and `AnotherModalCtrl` inject `$modalInstance` instead of `$modal`

http://plnkr.co/edit/wbFAzaRtTvcdCVHGfOcI?p=preview